# Getting to BER when trains are not running

Tags: public-transport, berlin

I'm planning to fly from Berlin Brandenburg airport next Tuesday afternoon and I planned on getting there by train from Berlin centre.

However, I know that there are rail strikes planned from Sunday until Tuesday and, as I understand, all trains are cancelled. I was wondering what (public transportation) routes should still be available despite the strikes?

Edit: it's a bit late, but since this became a hot network question, I think it's worth repeating here after comments: **the strike has been called off** and most trains run according to schedule (but don't take my word for it and do check your train if you might be affected).

Comment: Tricky. Taking public transportation on that day may be difficult especially if you have luggage.  The Berlin S-Bahn moves significantly more than 1 million passengers a day (not counting the regional trains): while busses and subway are running, they might be VERY crowded. Consider using a ride share (Uber or Miles) but I would expect peak pricing here as well. It depends a bit on the time of day:  I recommend giving yourself plenty of time and stay outside rush hours. Make sure you go to Terminal 1/2 NOT to Terminal 5

Comment: @Hilmar: I won't have much luggage, just my backpack. Hopefully I will manage, but yeah, I will make sure I have enough time!

Comment: It looks like most of the trains will run but do check if you decide on going by train as some companies might still be affected.

Comment: @Willeke: What do you mean? Is the strike cancelled?

Comment: Yes, the Deutsche Bahn and the trade union have agreed to: "Now to negotiate quickly and constructively, with the goal of an early conclusion". The S-Bahn should be running normally Tuesday.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would have probably missed this if it wasn't for you guys, this will (hopefully) simplify my itinerary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the Berliner Verkehrsbetriebe (BVG). They are not striking.

You can install the BVG **Fahrinfo** application and give in precise details.

Depending from where you start, find an underground connection that crosses the **U7** (most North/South lines cross it)

- **U9** (Bahnhof Zoo): U7: **Berliner Straße**
- **U6** (Bahnhof Friedrichstraße): U7: **Mehringdamm**
- **U8** (Alexanderplatz): U7: **Hermannplatz**

Below is a screenshot for Tuesday, 10:00.

Take the underground (**U7**) to **Rudow** (on the map where the blue line ends) and then the **X71** (every 10 minutes) to the Airport (Terminal 1-2).

An **ABC** ticket (€4.00) is required

- **or** an **AB** ticket (€3.20) **plus** a connection-card (**Anschlussfahrausweis**) for €2.00 (which you can stamp when the journey starts)

  - most of the Tourist/24h cards are for the **AB** area

Zone **C** starts at the city limits, which the X71 will cross. So the connection-card must be stamped at the latest when getting on the X71 Bus.

[image]

---

> @user253751
> The BVG app [**Fahrinfo**] is also very useful because it gives you very current routing based on very up-to-date conditions, even things like real-time train delays.
>
> Why, just yesterday I thought I was being smart by taking an earlier tram on a different route that would get me towards my destination, even though it wasn't indicated by the app.
>
> Turns out a segment of that route is closed for building work and replaced by bus, which is why it wasn't suggested.
>
> And yes, it shows you all services not just BVG services.

This is also true for special events, such as Marathons, which often block north/south bus connections on Saturday/Sundays. Based on the given date/time of arrival you can see if the bus line is effected or not, with alternative routes being suggested to bypass the area of the event.

The services (Bus, Trams, U-Bahn, S-Bahn) can be turned on/off effecting what is shown on the map and used for the suggested route. Pressing the icon can set the destination/starting point.

Comment: The BVG app is also very useful because it gives you very current routing based on very up-to-date conditions, even things like real-time train delays. Why, just yesterday I thought I was being smart by taking an earlier tram on a different route that would get me towards my destination, even though it wasn't indicated by the app. Turns out a segment of that route is closed for building work and replaced by bus, which is why it wasn't suggested. And yes, it shows you all services not just BVG services.